# Data is repeated in Flutter UI when reading from Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having a problem where data is repeated in my UI:

[image]

I'm putting the code but is giving it to me 3 times, how can I solve this?

code:
`

```
class GetUserName extends StatelessWidget {
  final String documentId;

  const GetUserName({Key? key, required this.documentId}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// Get the collection
    CollectionReference user = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: user.doc(documentId).get(),
      builder: ((context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data =
              snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return Text(
              "User Full Name: \n${data['first name']} ${data['last name']}");
        }
        return const Text('Loading...');
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

`

I tried to put the user information and it is givving me this error so I have not space and I don't know how to divide them.

Comment: It doesn't seem that the code you shared could be causing that. Are you sure you're not including `GetUserName` multiple time in its parent widget?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the info!, no, I'm using just a single GetUserName in the code...